# Syntax highlighting for C++ ,initializing with `=` vs `()`

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

Here is the example

```
int a = 5;
int c(5);
```

I hope the syntax highlighting works for you, if not then the way `a` and `c` are highlighted is different, shouldn't they be highlighted the same way?

`c` has the same highlighting as a function would have (bright orange)
whereas `a` has no highlight.

[image: highlight]

Comment: How does it work with Braces rather than Parenthesis? `int a = 5; int c{5};` is really the correct way to do it. Parens have been obsolete for some time.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Using braces work the same, It's just with Parens.I think a lot of people use `()` when creating objects and calling the constructor.

Comment: Is this site-specific or is the same issue on Stack Overflow? If it's at multiple sites, there's nothing we can do for you and you're better off at the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mast Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I need to test it at all the other sites. I believe they all use the same syntax highlighting engine, how can I move this question then?

Comment: You can not move this question. Please test it at Stack Overflow and another site, like Code Golf or Software Engineering and report back.

Comment: @Mast yes the same arises on those sites, I tested it on Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, and Code Review

Comment: If you're absolutely sure there's a bug, not a usage mistake, I recommend posting it on main meta as indicated above.

Comment: @Mast Yes i posted it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355620/syntax-highlighting-for-c-code-initializing-with-vs?noredirect=1#comment1188666_355620), also I'm unsure whether I should delete this question or not, what do you say?

Comment: Feel free to remove it.